# Gradle ERROR: ProductFlavor names cannot start with 'test'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Tried to name my productFlavor as "test" and received the error:

```
 ERROR: ProductFlavor names cannot start with 'test'
```

From the source code I see the simple check:

```
 private void addBuildType(BuildType buildType) {
    if (buildType.name.startsWith("test")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("BuildType names cannot start with 'test'")
    }...
}
```

Appears I can use names like "myTest", "aTest", etc., but not "test1", "test2" etc.
Any possible reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not well-suited for Stack Overflow, since only Developer X can answer them. Everyone else is limited to opinions. For example, my opinion is that since `test` is used as source set name already (for unit tests), they did not want a collision with build types and product flavors also using that name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see in this Google [repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/21b5320e57ba21f829ecbb4862cf0b9876e11778/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/AndroidPlugin.groovy#93) line 93

```
private void addBuildType(BuildType buildType) {
    if (buildType.name.startsWith("test")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("BuildType names cannot start with 'test'")
    }
    if (productFlavors.containsKey(buildType.name)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("BuildType names cannot collide with ProductFlavor names")
    }
    def sourceSet = project.sourceSets.add(buildType.name)
    BuildTypeData buildTypeData = new BuildTypeData(buildType, sourceSet, project)
    project.tasks.assemble.dependsOn buildTypeData.assembleTask
    buildTypes[buildType.name] = buildTypeData
}
```

So `addBuildType` method has its own exception about not using `test` name . you can't use this . and why they made this decision. No one can answer except google.

Comment: Because gradle gonna build task call `test` ,for example, `ktlintTestSourceSetCheck`. So the name test gonna conflict.

Comment: @theerasantonthongkam indeed